# Snackbar doesn't show in Material 3

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I'm trying material3 and I can't get my snackbar to show. This code worked in material2. When the snackbar is called for the column shifts down like I would expect but it's very brief, much shorter than a short duration snackbar and there is no message.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Snackbar(snackbarHostState: SnackbarHostState) {
    SnackbarHost(
        hostState = snackbarHostState,
        snackbar = { snackbarData: SnackbarData ->
            Card(
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(20.dp)
                    .wrapContentSize()
            ) {

                Text(text = snackbarData.visuals.message, fontSize = 30.sp)

            }
        }
    )
}
@Composable
fun LaunchSnackbar (snackbarHostState: SnackbarHostState, message: String) {
    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(message = message)
    }
}
val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
Snackbar(snackbarHostState)
LaunchSnackbar(snackbarHostState = snackbarHostState, message = "Incorrect")
```

It looked like the only thing I had to change was

```kotlin
snackbarData.message  
snackbarData.visual.message
```

Not sure what else is wrong.

Comment: Can you show more code? Are you using your `Snackbar` within an M3 `Scaffold`?

Comment: I've tried it both ways, within the Scaffold and placing Snackbar(snackbarHostState) where I would like it to appear in the column. Either way the behaviour is the same. The UI moves to make room for the snackbar but nothing appears and it's very fast, not 4 seconds or whatever a standard duration is. I've used Log.d and it's being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please can you share your `Scaffold`'s code. I would like to see where how you place your `SnackBarHost` in your `Scaffold`.
If you go to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material2-material3#scaffold,-snackbars), we see this:

```
val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

Scaffold(
    snackbarHost = { SnackbarHost(snackbarHostState) },
    content = {
        …
        scope.launch {
            snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(…)
        }
    }
)
```

This tells me that, from the two lines below (from the code you posted)

```
Snackbar(snackbarHostState)
LaunchSnackbar(snackbarHostState = snackbarHostState, message = "Incorrect")
```

we should replace the first line with the `Scaffold` to which you should pass your `Snackbar(snackbarHostState)`.
So if I repeat the documentation code, it would look something like:

```
val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

Scaffold(
    snackbarHost = { Snackbar(snackbarHostState) },
    content = {
        …
        scope.launch {
            snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(…)
        }
    }
)
LaunchSnackbar(snackbarHostState = snackbarHostState, message = "Incorrect")
```

Comment: I tried it again and it works. I had since refactored my code and where I'm using the snackbar is in an isolated module. Not sure what was really different about my previous usage. It works whether I place it in the scaffold or not. The reason I didn't have it in the scaffold was it would only appear on the bottom of the screen. Which is another question I have posted (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75621929/place-snackbar-above-soft-keyboard-using-a-scaffold). I'm thinking the answer is no but perhaps you know a definitive answer. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I was able to recreate the problem and found that the coroutine was being cancelled because the screen was being immediately recomposed after launching the snackbar. recompkotlinx.coroutines.    JobCancellationException: StandaloneCoroutine was cancelled; job=StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@1d130d0osed

Comment: Thank you for the follow up on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issues with what appears to also be the coroutines being cancelled upon recomposition and snack bars quickly disappearing faster than the designated duration. A solution that I have found to work is to create a scaffold around your NavHost and assign the snackbarhost to this scaffold, executing the launched effect in this composable.

One issue that ive also come across is forgetting that if your snackbar message state is the the same, as in the same message, the LaunchedEffect will not execute since technically your message state didnt change. To solve this in a simple way is to modify your message type to a data class that has a timestamp of the time the message is emitted onto the messages sharedFlow.

```
 @Composable
 fun NavHostComposable(
      viewModel: ViewModel
 ) {
     val navController = rememberNavController()

     val snackbarHostState = remember{SnackbarHostState()}
     val snackbarMessages by viewModel.snackbarMessages.collectAsState(initial = null)

     LaunchedEffect(key1 = snackbarMessages) {
         snackbarMessages?.let { snackBarMessage ->
              //Show snackbar message on every non-null value
              snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                 message = snackBarMessage.message,
                 duration = SnackbarDuration.Short
              )
          }
     }
     Scaffold(
         snackbarHost = { SnackbarHost(snackbarHostState) },
     ) { innerPadding ->
         NavHost(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding ),
            navController = navController,
            ...
         ) {

    ...

         }
     }
}
```